# Set virtualenv for file in Visual Studio Code python

Tags: python, virtualenv, visual-studio-code

I'm playing with Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu. One big problem is I can't figure out how to attach a virtualenv to a file. So, I open the file. On the lower left corner, I see the default path to the system python executable:

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

when I click on it, a list with two paths is shown on the top middle box (both are the default system python's).

I tried to set the `python.venvPath` (in green in the right window).
but it does not work.

My question is: how to assign a virtualenv to a project, so that whenever I open 
that file, it uses that venv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply set the *pythonPath* variable in the local `.vscode/settings.json` to the python that should be used, like so:

```
"python.pythonPath": "~/.virtualenvs/<my_virtual_env>/bin/python"
```

Code then automatically sources the virtualenv activate script before running files (like debugging or "run python file in terminal").

I use Ubuntu 18.04, Code 1.33.0 and Python Plugin 2019.3 from Microsoft